# How to persist authentication after reload using react auth kit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, basic-authentication

I am new to the concept of authentications in apps, especially using tokens. I found the react-auth-kit library to help me do the authentication. I have a simple login using a username and a password with a set backend that works well on Postman. I managed to also authenticate the user into the dashboard, but when I reload the page, the user is sent back to the login page.

I tried using sessionStorage which someone pointed out as a security risk in a blog and didn't succeed either. I did not see the concept in the documentation. Could someone point me in the right direction, maybe a better library or a workaround on this one?

```js
// In my app component...
import Login from "./components/Login";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import { useIsAuthenticated } from 'react-auth-kit'
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const redirect = () => {
    if (isAuthState) {
      return <Dashboard />
    } else {
      return <Login />
    }
  }
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        {/* <Login /> */}
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={ <Login /> } />
          <Route path='/Dashboard' element={redirect()} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

```js
// In my Login component this is the handler for the form. I used react-hook-form for validation...

const signIn = useSignIn()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const login: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = (data) => {
    axios.post<SignInType>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/login', data)
      .then((res) => {
        if(res.data.status === 200) {
          if(signIn({token: res.data.token, tokenType: 'Bearer', expiresIn: 300000})) {
            navigate('/dashboard')
          }
        } else {
          setCredentialsError('Invalid credentials, please try again...')
        }
      })
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found a solution yet, do make sure you have authState defined in your signIn() function.

Answer (score 0):

Please add authState attributes to signIn method like below!

```
signIn({token: res.data.token, tokenType: 'Bearer', expiresIn: 300000, authState: {something: true}})
```